# Entity Framework Core 5.0 Warning limiting operator ('Skip'/'Take') without an 'OrderBy' operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am writing a .net Core 3.1 application and have recently updated it to Entity Framework Core 5.0. Running the application has since started showing warnings as follows:

> The query uses a row limiting operator ('Skip'/'Take') without an
> 'OrderBy' operator. This may lead to unpredictable results.

I have reviewed every instance of my code that would use .Skip or .Take or both and they all have a OrderBy clause.

My question is, are there any flags I can set with

> DbContextOptiosnBuilder() .ConfigureWarnings(w
> => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.???))

to help determine where these .Skip and .Take queries are being ran or any way to trigger a stack trace with this warning to narrow down the cause.

Alternatively, how can one go about silencing this warning from the console?

Comment: Is the `OrderBy` *before or after* the Skip/Take?

Comment: OrderBy is before

Comment: the eventd I was looking for was:`CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`EventId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.eventid?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) value you are looking for is [`CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.coreeventid.rowlimitingoperationwithoutorderbywarning?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0).

> A query uses a row limiting operation (Skip/Take) without OrderBy which may lead to unpredictable results.
>
> This event is in the [DbLoggerCategory.Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbloggercategory.query?view=efcore-5.0) category.

As usual, the default action is `Log`, and you can turn it to error

```
.Throw(CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning)
```

or suppress it

```
.Ignore(CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning)
```

Comment: I will give this a shot and see if it gets triggered. I am starting to suspect it may be a warning from another library.

Comment: @JordanBrobyn Another library, seriously? The exception message exactly matches the explanation from the documentation (included in the answer for your and future readers convenience).

Comment: I mean that a library I am using may be using some Linq query that uses.Take.Skip without OrderBy that I do not have control of.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I was able to determine where the warning was being thrown.

Even though the error mentions, .Skip and.Take, performing a query like this will also trigger this warning:

`_dbContext.Users.Include(r => r.Roles).Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Hmm, interesting, by documentation there is another one specifically for First/FirstOrDefault called [CoreEventId.FirstWithoutOrderByAndFilterWarning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.coreeventid.firstwithoutorderbyandfilterwarning?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreEventId.FirstWithoutOrderByAndFilterWarning);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0). But I see they've been obsoleted in EFC3 and un-obsoleted in EFC5. so it's a (typical for EFC) mess.

Answer (score 14):

In fact, you get this warning EVEN if you use a `FirstOrDefault` (or `SingleOrDefault`) on a primary key selection i.e.

```
context.dbsetXXX.SingleOrDefaultAsync(xxx => xxx.ID == id);
```

It seems to be due in how this query in badly mapped in T-SQL - using a `TAKE(1)` statement.
So for now I would just Ignore the warning ( using `.Ignore(CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning) ...`)

Comment: Same warning occurs with the Query Splitting feature: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22579

Comment: Ignoring the warning doesn't seem to work with `FromSqlRaw()`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the OrderBy/OrderByDescending methods should be invoked before Skip/Take so that the results are not already paginated

Comment: OP already stated that he is already using OrderBy/OrderByDescending at every Skip/Take