# Error with DbContext after upgrading to .NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application, which I upgraded to .NET 6 following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

All of my unit tests are passing.

When I run the application, some queries are working and some are failing with this error:

> An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.)'

[image]

I took one of the failing queries and put it in a Sandbox Unit Test and ran it. It runs fine. So there is something wrong with the dependency injection of the `DbContext`.

I tried deleting all `obj` and `bin` folders, restarting Visual Studio, restarting my computer, none of which helped.

Here is how I am registering my `DbContext`:

```
var myConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(nameof(MyDbContext));
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
});
```

The app was working fine before the upgrade.

How do I fix this?

```
System.AggregateException   
HResult=0x80131500  
Message=An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.)  
Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging  

StackTrace:  
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Define>g__Log|0(ILogger logger, Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Define>b__1(ILogger logger, Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.EventDefinition.Log[TLoggerCategory](IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreLoggerExtensions.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateTake(ShapedQueryExpression source, Expression count)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at My.PartnerQueries.<GetIndexViewModel>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\my\source\repos\my\My.Services\Partners\PartnerQueries.cs:line 21
   
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:  
[External Code]
   
Inner Exception 1:  
InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

.NET SDK 6.0.200.  Visual Studio 2022 (64-bit) 17.1.0

Comment: Please show an example of the DbContext that's failing, and how it gets created or resolved from the container. In other words, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  One of the queries that was failing before my reboot is now working.

Comment: The error seems to have something to do with logging. Please provide a full stack trace.

Comment: Normally I don't like cloning over again, but in this case, I think I will do it to get a clean solution.

Comment: I tried running outside of IIS Express and the issue remains.  Doing a fresh git clone did not seem to help either.

Comment: @mason I added a query.

Comment: I moved the `.Take` after the `.OrderBy` and the query seems to work now...  I need to stop for the day.  See you tomorrow!

Comment: Okay, so from the stack trace it's clear that the error has something to do with logging. Do you have some sort of logging set up to go to a database on your Microsoft.Extensions.Logging? Where's the configuration for that?

Comment: The cause is `RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning`. Your code is using `.Skip` and `.Take` without an `.OrderBy()`. However, are you trying to write log messages into a database, but that database has no connection string?

Comment: OK.  Yeah you were pointing in the right direction.  There was a problem with my NLog database connection string!  Wow, that was really confusing.  I fixed the connection string and now all of the queries are working!  Phew!  If you want to write an answer, I will give you the credit.

Comment: It really shouldn't have been that confusing. The stack trace was pretty clear that it was trying to log to a DB and missing a connection string, so the logical thing to do was check the connection string in your logging configuration. Make sure you take the time to read and comprehend your errors in the future, as it will save you a lot of time and hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the sage words, but an exception on multiple different queries that mentions a ConnectionString property of the the DbContext... In hindsight it is obvious, but you can understand my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details are all there in the stack trace. The trick is knowing how to read it.

First the exception `Message`

```cs
Message=An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.)
```

So you're trying to log something into a database, but there's no connection string. If you fix that, diagnosing future errors is going to be much easier.

But what called `.Log` to trigger this?

```cs
...
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.EventDefinition.Log[TLoggerCategory](IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreLoggerExtensions.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics)
...
```

Thankfully the EF Core team have written a helper method to log / ignore / throw  for various diagnostic messages, which puts the error right there in the method name. A quick google search for the method name leads to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311789/entity-framework-core-5-0-warning-limiting-operator-skip-take-without-an), which should help to resolve the root cause of the problem.

Personally I would configure all diagnostics to throw in a debug build. Then as you understand what each error means, disable those warnings you are comfortable with.

```cs
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => { ... })
    .ConfigureWarnings(w => w
#if DEBUG
        // throw on all EF query diagnostics in debug builds (eg query should be split)
        .Default(WarningBehavior.Throw)
#endif
        .Log(CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning)
    );
```